# Generate divs in random coordinates and random sizes without overlapping

Tags: javascript, html, css, collision-detection

The assignment requires me to create divs with random size and coordinates inside of a parent div. Additionally each of these divs have to be movable on click but also their collision must be prevented so on collision they must be stopped. Additionally, vanilla JavaScript is to be used only. So no additional libraries, or even HTML canvas can be used.

I have finished the displaying of the divs with random size and coordinates but can't prevnt them from overlapping and don't know where to start with the moving option. Here is the code for more clear picture:

HTML:

```js
const container = document.querySelector('.wrapper')

function backgroundColor() {
  var color = '#d1d11d';
  return color;
}


function getRndInteger(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
}

function addDiv() {
  var div = document.createElement("div");
  const clear = document.getElementById('clear')

  div.className = 'box';
  div.style.top = getRndInteger(1, 800) + 'px';
  div.style.left = getRndInteger(1, 800) + 'px';
  div.style.height = getRndInteger(1, 100) + 'px';
  div.style.width = getRndInteger(1, 100) + 'px';
  div.style.background = backgroundColor();
  document.querySelector('.wrapper').appendChild(div);

  clear.addEventListener('click', () => {
    div.remove();
  });
}

document.querySelector('#create').addEventListener('click', addDiv);
```

```css
.box {
  position: absolute;
}

.wrapper {
  height: 900px;
  width: 900px;
  background-color: blue;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class='wrapper'></div>
  <button id="create">pressme</button>
  <button id="clear">clear</button>
  <button id="drag">drag</button>

  <script src="generate.js"></script>
  <script src="drag.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Try to break this into more specific problems. Like, first how do you know if a rect is being overlapped by another one (collision detection)?

Comment: @AlexRintt I don't know, thats the thing. I don't have a clue how to do that

Comment: At its simplest, you can ascertain the positions of each rectangle's 4 corners. When you create a new one you know its (potential) 4 corner positions so you can loop through all existing rectangles looking to see if the ranges overlap (draw a couple of overlapping rectangles on a piece of paper and work out how you would do that).